# How to link to VTK library in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vtk

My system specifications are :
a) Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit
b) Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

I compiled VTK 6.1.0 from source using cmake 2.8.12.2 The paths and the process involved in the build are briefly outlined below (**The library was built with the SHARED_LIBS = ON because I needed to wrap python and wrapping required building with SHARED_LIBS**) 
:
a) I unzipped the source in C:\Libraries\VTK-6.1.0 and made a folder \build inside it 
b) I did the configuration and generation with the option to use Intel TBB turned ON.
c) The configuration type was MinSizeRel (which i guess is something like Release only.) I just removed the option Debug from CMAKE configuration type and rest remained the same. When I finally built it , it was built in MinSizeRel.

d) Then I opened ALL_BUILD project in \build folder and built the library
e) Subsequently I ran the INSTALL project with administrative privilages .

Then I saw that in C:\Program Files\VTK there are bin , include and lib folders created and filled up with files

Then I wrote a sample example VTK code taken from VTK wiki page. I set the additional include directories as that of C:\Program Files\VTK\include and that of tbb include directory. 
For additional library directories,  I used the \VTK\lib folder in C:\Program Files and the tbb lib directory.

Now when I try to build the project,  I face the following linking errors one of which I am mentioning below :

> vtk_1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class vtkPolyDataMapper *
>   _*cdecl vtkPolyDataMapper::New(void)" (*_imp_?New@vtkPolyDataMapper@@SAPEAV1@XZ)

I have tried many things, but nothing worked. Some of the unsuccessful things I tried were :-

1. Changing the configuration types of the visual studio project from win32 to x64 in both debug and release modes

2) Providing the paths to the DLL files of VTK and TBB in the library directories for the project.

I do not have a deep knowledge of visual studio. I just work with C++ as a programmer and have worked in Visual studio only seldomly. It seems to me that somehow linking to obj files is not happening here. How do I correct the situation ?

Ujjwal

Comment: I highly recommend using CMake to generate the project file for your application. It will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: Also I recommend not building the INSTALL target of VTK. The reason is whatever configuration you install is the only configuration you can build your applications with. So if you installed release VTK you can not safely use your application in Debug mode. Instead of building the INSTALL target when you configure your application with CMake-gui set VTK_DIR to be the root folder where you built VTK. This should be the folder containing the CMakeCache.txt

Comment: Assuming that I am okay with working with applications in Release Mode (as that is what concerns me primarily !!!), with respect to my present configuration, how should I successfully compile and build my programs ? 
I am not properly aware of how to use CMake with Visual studio for this purpose in detail

Comment: Check out the vtk wiki examples. There are hundreds of examples containing CMakeLists.txt files that you can use CMake to generate Visual Studio projects.

Comment: Also with CMake you compile your projects pretty much in the same steps you compiled VTK (out of source building, configure and generate in the cmake-gui ...) however you have to create  CMakeLists.txt file for your project.

Comment: Have you added appropriate *.lib files to your project properties? E. g. Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input, then for that particular error you mentioned you need to add vtkRenderingCore-6.1.lib (I suspect the '-6.1' part may vary). I can hardly believe you'd miss something as basic as that if you were able to get through the horrors of CMake, but who knows...

Answer (score 1):

According to [How to Get VTK Working on Your Home Machine](http://www.cs.uakron.edu/~xiao/visualization/VTK-Installation-Tutorial.html), you may need to put several file names at Additional Dependencies in Properties as well.

In general, the Visual Studio project Properties have three information. First, include directories at Include Directories under VC++ Directories. Second one is  library directories at Library Directories under VC++ Directories. Last one is Additional Dependencies at Input under Linker. I see you did the first two things, so please try the last one.

Also depending on setting, you may need dll (dynamically linked library) in the same folder, where your executable file(s) located.

Another thing specially with the VTK, please verify you run INSTALL project. I see ALL_BUILD, INSTALL, and ZERO_CHECK project in my VTK 6.3 project. I believe the INSTALL project will actually install the VTK at a certain folder such as Program Files/VTK.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build with CMake and chose to generate for 32 bit dlls. Additional to the normal settings select the examples which will create example projects for you.

The examples generated were readily build-able and working.
Once you investigate the examples you will get all the information like additional includes links etc from examples projects in VTK.